# Activity Do not clear from back stack even From Method Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP

Tags: android, android-studio, start-activity

I want to move to another activity but before i want to clear all the other activity. I know the method Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP but it does not work when i back pressed after moving then it again show the previous one activity.
My code is

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, WelcomeActivity.class);
 intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
 startActivity(intent);
 progressDialog.dismiss();
```

Thanks Advance

Comment: `CLEAR_TOP` only works if the Activity launch mode is `singleTop`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes it doesn't work you should add this line in your code

```
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | 
        Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```

It will help you and hopefully your issue will resolve.
I've added this line in your code and after adding that line your code will look like this

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, WelcomeActivity.class);
 intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK |
    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
 startActivity(intent);
 progressDialog.dismiss();
```

Replace your code with the above code.

Answer (score 2):

Add three flags:

```
 intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
 intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
 intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```

Answer (score 2):

CLEAR_TOP only work if you have single Top means only one activity So you also need to add Intent. Clear Task and Intent. New Task with your code that look like this in the below code

```
   intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK |
    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```